# The application is incorrectly configured Google Play Game Services

Tags: android, service, configuration

Mabe will I look like a true newbie, and mabe am I, but I'd request some help from you !

I have done all this :

added and linked my app in the Dev Console (game services)
included the App_id into my app/manifest
added BaseGameActivity and GameHelper to my project (from GitHub)
added the google-play-services library to my project
extended BaseGameActivity
I took App_id from console, it's 100% correct.
I'm trying to log in with an test account
SHA1 and package name 100% correct.

I have put the app id & achievement ids both in the ids.xml file & strings file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="app_id">239----------</string> .......
```

And I still can't get rid of this "Application not correctly configured"..... neither on the test one neither on the signed one.
I have created two client IDs in Google Developer Console>Credentials with both the test & signed sha1, correct information & deep linking successively disabled & enabled.

I'm starting to be bored.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking a new app to my dev console with exactly the same parameters solved my problem :)

Comment: Hey, I can't manage to fix this-- If you could help me over teamviewer (or another remote desktop program) I'd be glad to pay you. I have also changed my packaging and even created a new application on the play market, redid all of my achievements and whatnot just to try it this way, but failed.

Answer (score 3):

After 4 hours of researching, i found the solution to fix this error successfully:

When developing, make sure you sign the **SHA1** with you **debug.keystore** NOT release keystore.

 Good luck!