# Google Play Games login fails. (Google Play services)

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

The application is loaded into the developer console. The application is published in internal testing. The group with testers is activated. Settings published, services published.

The SHA1 key from Game Maker Studio 2 was copied to the console when the application was loaded.

In the game to check the authorization, the player's name is displayed on the screen (PlayerName = async_load [? "Name"]; the default is "Anon"). When you start the game, the Google Play Games splash screen is displayed. I choose my account. Loading (rotating circle). After loading, the player's name is changed to "Not logged in".

My log file: https://pastebin.com/c87680ua

Excerpt from the log:

```
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: **** APP NOT CORRECTLY CONFIGURED TO USE GOOGLE PLAY GAME SERVICES
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: **** This is usually caused by one of these reasons:
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: **** (1) Your package name and certificate fingerprint do not match
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: **** the client ID you registered in Developer Console.
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: **** (2) Your App ID was incorrectly entered.
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: **** (3) Your game settings have not been published and you are 
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: **** trying to log in with an account that is not listed as
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: **** a test account.
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: ****
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: **** To help you debug, here is the information about this app
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: **** Package name : com.***.***
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: **** Cert SHA1 fingerprint: 4F********D0
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: **** App ID from manifest : 51*******38
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: ****
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: **** Check that the above information matches your setup in 
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: **** Developer Console. Also, check that you're logging in with the
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: **** right account (it should be listed in the Testers section if
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: **** your project is not yet published).
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: ****
3221 8167 E SignInAuthenticator: **** For more information, refer to the troubleshooting guide:
```

In the beginning thought that the problem was SHA1. Later abandoned this idea. App ID is correct.

P.S. In-app purchases are functioning successfully

**UPDATE:**

Once again checked the key. Replaced (according to this guide - http://forum.hellroom.ru/index.php?topic=25526.msg315187). The situation as a whole has not changed, but the log has changed! The “error” given in the question above has disappeared. True to understand the situation did not become easier. Can you help? Here is a log: https://pastebin.com/CX9xG9nW

The only thing that I discovered:

```
02-13 19:36:45.722 13302 13302 I yoyo    : Login failed! Exception:  com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8:
```

Log with not silent login: https://pastebin.com/f81qFwKM

Comment: Have you tried looking at the following SO posts: [22507927](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507927), [23460407](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460407/), [25949907](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949907/), [22417225](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417225/)?

Comment: Once again checked the key. Replaced (according to one guide). The situation as a whole has not changed, but the log has changed!

The “error” given in the question above has disappeared.

True to understand the situation did not become easier. Can you help? Here is a log: https://pastebin.com/CX9xG9nW

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the new log, rather than have a link to an external site?

Comment: Sorry, but the log is very large. It is not placed in the length of the question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Your first log mentions about configuration error.

```
APP NOT CORRECTLY CONFIGURED TO USE GOOGLE PLAY GAME SERVICES
```

If you use Google App Signing, you have to use SHA1 from App Sign Certificato not from Upload Certificate.

[Google sign in failed com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619229/google-sign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10)

This post will help you maybe